# Search function adding an index on each new line

Tags: java, search, loops, for-loop

So I have been writing a chat client and I decided to make a search function so you could find a particular word in the chat history and it selects it. However, what happens is that each line below the initial line the selection is that many indexes right of the word it should select. Is there a new line character or index locations I am missing?

How do I get around the indexes changing on each line? 
Or perhaps there is an issue in my code:

```
private void nextButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    toSearchText = searchText.getText();
    if (!toSearchText.equals("")) {
        for (int i = index; i < searchBlock.length(); i++) {
            if (searchBlock.charAt(i) == toSearchText.charAt(0)) {
                System.out.println("found first char- Starting check loop." + i + j + "::" + count);
                for (j = i; j < i + toSearchText.length(); j++) {
                    System.out.println("J" + j + " II " + innerIndex);
                    if (searchBlock.charAt(j) == toSearchText.charAt(innerIndex)) {
                        innerIndex++;
                        count++;
                        System.out.println("found char:" + innerIndex + " - " + searchBlock.charAt(j));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Not the word");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(j);

            if (count == toSearchText.length()) {
                if (searchBlock.substring(i, j).equals(toSearchText)) {
                    System.out.println(searchBlock.substring(i, j) + " and " + toSearchText);
                    System.out.println("focusing");
                    ClientWindow.mainText.requestFocusInWindow();
                    ClientWindow.mainText.select(i, j);
                    count = 0;
                    innerIndex = 0;
                    index = i + toSearchText.length();
                    if (index > searchBlock.length()) {
                        index = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("focus refused");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Search Finished");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So to get around the issue of there being an extra index on each line, I wrote a method to count the lines and then minused that value from the indexes.

```
private int checkLine(int position){
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner text = new Scanner(searchBlock.substring(0,position));

    while(text.hasNextLine()){
        counter++;
        text.nextLine();
    }
    return counter - 1;
}
```